# How to Update price automatically in Product page when qty or custom options changed?

Tags: product, price, upgrade, magento1.9.3

I want to update the price automatically without refreshing the page once the Qty has been changed. How to do this?

Comment: Price on product page(for 1pc product? for quick cart?)? Price on cart? Can You write more about your problem?

Comment: Once the product Quantity has increased in the product page or some different options like size, color etc. selected means it should automatically load the updated price for the user. How to make it auto update in price without refreshing or doing nothing in that page. Is it clear now?

Comment: For size etc You can use configurable products and depends on sizes, colors etc set different prices for each simple product. I think you can not use magento tools for change price for products depends on qty on product pages. You have to write it manualy (using Ajax - it allows for change content without load page). Also You can use Category / Cart price rules. It allows for add discounts depends for eg qty.